# BlindSSLFactory for secure LDAP Authentication bypass doesn't work on production

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl, ldap, ssl-certificate

I've a strange problem I can't get over since days, so I gave up and decided to consult to knowledgeable stackoverflow members.

**Which java version I use?**

Amazon coretto 1.8.0_275

**What I want to achieve?**

In my application, user has to authenticate himself using secure ldap connection. After authentication from LDAP directory, user will be redirected to the his homepage. However, I want that the certification check should be bypassed during the connection to the ldap server over secure port.

**What I did so far and what works?**

From other posts, I found that I need to use BlindSSLFactory class to bypass the certification check and inject this class to properties during ldap query, I added this to my project and If I run the project from **eclipse**, everything works absolutely fine and certification check is bypassed and user logs in. Note that: In my java truststore i have no signed certification whatsoever.

**What doesn't work?**

If I compile the project, with an installer I created, and run it as an application(not from eclipse, rather from its own installer), I get the following error.
Note: I debug the following line and it prints true, as I set it before the project runs:
-Dcom.sun.jndi.ldap.object.disableEndpointIdentification:

```
javax.naming.CommunicationException: simple bind failed: 10.148.129.11:636
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.authenticate(LdapClient.java:219) ~[na:1.8.0_275]
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.connect(LdapCtx.java:2897) ~[na:1.8.0_275]
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.<init>(LdapCtx.java:347) ~[na:1.8.0_275]
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getLdapCtxFromUrl(LdapCtxFactory.java:225) ~[na:1.8.0_275]
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURL(LdapCtxFactory.java:189) ~[na:1.8.0_275]
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURLs(LdapCtxFactory.java:243) ~[na:1.8.0_275]
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getLdapCtxInstance(LdapCtxFactory.java:154) ~[na:1.8.0_275]
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getInitialContext(LdapCtxFactory.java:84) ~[na:1.8.0_275]
at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:684) ~[na:1.8.0_275]
at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:313) ~[na:1.8.0_275]
at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:244) ~[na:1.8.0_275]
at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:216) ~[na:1.8.0_275]
at javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext.<init>(InitialDirContext.java:101) ~[na:1.8.0_275]
at com.ricoh.sdced.festo.pab.web.login.LdapAuthentication.createLoginSession(LdapAuthentication.java:78) [classes!/:na]
at com.ricoh.sdced.festo.pab.web.login.LdapAuthentication.startLoginSession(LdapAuthentication.java:43) [classes!/:na]
at com.ricoh.sdced.festo.pab.web.views.LoginView.performLogin(LoginView.java:54) [classes!/:na]
at com.ricoh.sdced.festo.pab.web.views.LoginView.lambda$createLoginLayout$565279a2$1(LoginView.java:47) [classes!/:na]
at com.vaadin.flow.component.ComponentEventBus.fireEventForListener(ComponentEventBus.java:205) ~[flow-server-2.1.5.jar!/:2.1.5]
at com.vaadin.flow.component.ComponentEventBus.handleDomEvent(ComponentEventBus.java:373) ~[flow-server-2.1.5.jar!/:2.1.5]
at com.vaadin.flow.component.ComponentEventBus.lambda$addDomTrigger$dd1b7957$1(ComponentEventBus.java:264) ~[flow-server-2.1.5.jar!/:2.1.5]
at com.vaadin.flow.internal.nodefeature.ElementListenerMap.lambda$fireEvent$2(ElementListenerMap.java:441) ~[flow-server-2.1.5.jar!/:2.1.5]
at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1259) ~[na:1.8.0_275]
at com.vaadin.flow.internal.nodefeature.ElementListenerMap.fireEvent(ElementListenerMap.java:441) ~[flow-server-2.1.5.jar!/:2.1.5]
at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.rpc.EventRpcHandler.handleNode(EventRpcHandler.java:59) ~[flow-server-2.1.5.jar!/:2.1.5]
at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.rpc.AbstractRpcInvocationHandler.handle(AbstractRpcInvocationHandler.java:64) ~[flow-server-2.1.5.jar!/:2.1.5]
at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocationData(ServerRpcHandler.java:402) ~[flow-server-2.1.5.jar!/:2.1.5]
at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.lambda$handleInvocations$1(ServerRpcHandler.java:383) ~[flow-server-2.1.5.jar!/:2.1.5]
at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1259) ~[na:1.8.0_275]
at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocations(ServerRpcHandler.java:383) ~[flow-server-2.1.5.jar!/:2.1.5]
at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleRpc(ServerRpcHandler.java:318) ~[flow-server-2.1.5.jar!/:2.1.5]
at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UidlRequestHandler.java:89) ~[flow-server-2.1.5.jar!/:2.1.5]
at com.vaadin.flow.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:40) ~[flow-server-2.1.5.jar!/:2.1.5]
at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1540) ~[flow-server-2.1.5.jar!/:2.1.5]
at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:247) ~[flow-server-2.1.5.jar!/:2.1.5]
at com.vaadin.flow.spring.SpringServlet.service(SpringServlet.java:95) ~[vaadin-spring-12.1.2.jar!/:na]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:4.0.FR]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:459) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:352) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:312) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletForwardingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletForwardingController.java:141) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:177) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:52) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:4.0.FR]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:4.0.FR]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:93) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1589) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[na:1.8.0_275]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[na:1.8.0_275]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_275]
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection or outbound has closed
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppOutputStream.write(SSLSocketImpl.java:967) ~[na:1.8.0_275]
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82) ~[na:1.8.0_275]
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140) ~[na:1.8.0_275]
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.writeRequest(Connection.java:448) ~[na:1.8.0_275]
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.writeRequest(Connection.java:421) ~[na:1.8.0_275]
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.ldapBind(LdapClient.java:359) ~[na:1.8.0_275]
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.authenticate(LdapClient.java:214) ~[na:1.8.0_275]
... 88 common frames omitted
```

**How is my logic in the code?**

```
public class BlindSSLSocketFactory extends SocketFactory {

private static SocketFactory blindFactory = null;
/**
 * Builds an ALL trusting "blind" ssl socket factory.
 */
static {
// create a trust manager that will purposefully fall down on the
// job
    TrustManager[] blindTrustMan = new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return null;
        }

        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] c, String a) {
        }

        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] c, String a) {
        }
    } };

    // create our "blind" ssl socket factory with our lazy trust manager
    try {
        SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        sc.init(null, blindTrustMan, new java.security.SecureRandom());
        blindFactory = sc.getSocketFactory();
    } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * @see javax.net.SocketFactory#getDefault()
 */
public static SocketFactory getDefault() {
    return new BlindSSLSocketFactory();
}

/**
 * @see javax.net.SocketFactory#createSocket(java.lang.String, int)
 */
public Socket createSocket(String arg0, int arg1) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
    return blindFactory.createSocket(arg0, arg1);
}

/**
 * @see javax.net.SocketFactory#createSocket(java.net.InetAddress, int)
 */
public Socket createSocket(InetAddress arg0, int arg1) throws IOException {
    return blindFactory.createSocket(arg0, arg1);
}

/**
 * @see javax.net.SocketFactory#createSocket(java.lang.String, int,
 *      java.net.InetAddress, int)
 */
public Socket createSocket(String arg0, int arg1, InetAddress arg2, int arg3)
        throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
    return blindFactory.createSocket(arg0, arg1, arg2, arg3);
}

/**
 * @see javax.net.SocketFactory#createSocket(java.net.InetAddress, int,
 *      java.net.InetAddress, int)
 */
public Socket createSocket(InetAddress arg0, int arg1, InetAddress arg2, int arg3) throws IOException {
    return blindFactory.createSocket(arg0, arg1, arg2, arg3);
}
```

}

And my LDAP login class where I inject this blindSSLFactory Class

```
@Component
public class LdapAuthentication {

private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

private String username;

private String password;

private boolean isLoggedIn;

public LdapAuthentication() {
}

public void startLoginSession(String username, String password)
        throws NamingException {
    
    logger.info("preparing user login details...");
    
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    
    logger.info("user login will be attempted for user: " + this.username);

    this.isLoggedIn = createLoginSession(this.username, this.password);
    
    logger.info("login attempt success result: " + this.isLoggedIn); 
}

private boolean createLoginSession(String username, String password)
        throws NamingException {

    logger.info("creating a LDAP Authentication session...");
    logger.info("System property value for            -Dcom.sun.jndi.ldap.object.disableEndpointIdentification:"
            + System.getProperty("com.sun.jndi.ldap.object.disableEndpointIdentification"));

    String ldapServerUrl = buildLdapPrefix()
            + SettingsResolver.getInstance().getSetting(
                    "ldap.server.address")
            + ":"
            + SettingsResolver.getInstance().getSetting(
                    "ldap.server.port.number");

    logger.info("LDAP authentication URL: " + ldapServerUrl);

    Properties props = new Properties();
    
    //use this line if you wanna discard ssl certificate validation
    props.put("java.naming.ldap.factory.socket",
            BlindSSLSocketFactory.class.getName());
    
    props.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
            "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    props.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, ldapServerUrl);
    props.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, username);
    props.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);

    InitialDirContext context = null;
    try {
        context = new InitialDirContext(props);
        SearchControls controls = new SearchControls();
        controls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
        NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> results = context.search(
                toDC(SettingsResolver.getInstance().getSetting(
                        "ldap.server.domain.name")), String.format(
                        "(& (userPrincipalName=%s)(objectClass=user))",
                        this.username), controls);
        
        return results.hasMore();
    } catch (NamingException namingException) {
        logger.error(
                "Exception occurred while authenticating to LDAP Server: ",
                namingException);

        throw namingException;
    } finally {
        try {
            if (context != null)
                context.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
    }
}

private static String toDC(String username) {
    String result = "";
    String[] parts = username.split("\\.");
    for (int index = 0; index < parts.length - 1; index++)
        result = result.concat("DC=").concat(parts[index]).concat(",");
    return result.concat("DC=").concat(parts[parts.length - 1]);
}

public boolean isUserLoggedIn() {
    return this.isLoggedIn;
}

private String buildLdapPrefix() {
    String securePortEnabled = SettingsResolver.getInstance().getSetting(
            "ldap.server.secure.port.enabled");

    if (securePortEnabled.contains("true")) {
        return "ldaps://";
    } else {
        return "ldap://";
    }
}
```

}

Comment: no help from senior developers? :(

Comment: Hi @Ahmet Eroğlu. I will reply here instead in the answer. It is not very likely, but the indicated change in the properties can be motivated with the _sanification_ process performed on the `ResourceManager` class when [initializing](https://github.com/corretto/corretto-8/blob/a6b2628f8074004f2c10bd7c276543a1acba412f/src/jdk/src/share/classes/com/sun/naming/internal/ResourceManager.java#L198-L246) the dir context. Perhaps, when you run the app in eclipse it has the full jre configuration and it is providing some defaults. Please, can you verify this term by debugging the appropriate code?

Comment: You can verify the actual properties associated with the context like this: `Hashtable<?,?> actualEnvit'ronment = context.getEnvironment();`. Another test you can do, and in order to provide some level of property configuration isolation, is indicating the `com.sun.naming.disable.app.resource.files` configuration property in your environment.

Comment: @jccampanero Dear jccampanero, first of all thank you so much for you help, I'm so sorrry but your eplanation was so technical for me, as I'm a junior developer. could please tell me what to do more precisely and also how to do it and why? I didnt understand ur explanation so much :(( Thank you so so so much in advance.. Should I put this "com.sun.naming.disable.app.resource.files" to my props with the value of true u meant?

Comment: Hi Ahmed. Please, sorry, I will try to explain myself better. Yes, I suggested you to try several things. On one hand, you can include the one `Hashtable actualEnvironment = context.getEnvironment()` right after your line `context = new InitialDirContext(props);`. It will provide you valuable information about if any code is changing the properties you  configured, in Eclipse and in you production application. If that were the case, you can set the internal property `com.sun.naming.disable.app.resource.files` to `true`, also in eclipse and in the installer, and see what happens.

Comment: Setting this property to `true` will instruct your code to not include any application or are specific configuration. Please, in any way, as it is something internal of the JDK libraries, first, it should be tested carefully, and depending of the JDK implementation perhaps it can be not portable. The idea is only test the code and see if the change provides some insight into the problem.

Comment: As a side note, and it probably has nothing to do with the problem resolution if the program is working find in eclipse, but maybe you need to indicate the property `Context.SECURITY_PROTOCOL` with a value of `ssl`. Please, see: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jndi/jndi-ldap-gl.html#SSL. If you have any question and you think I can be of any help, please, tell me, I will be glad to help you if I can.

Comment: @jccampanero Dear jccampanero thank you so so so much for your detailed explanations im so thankful you cant know... So here is what has happened after your suggestions. First of all I wanna say something else, this also happened before adding your two suggestions. When I remote debug the application, and it comes to this line of adding the properties, i make f6 to step over. Normally this should go to next line you know, but what happens is that, as soon as it comes to this first props.put  line, it starts to act weirdly, sometimes it jumps two lines at once. and laso when i hover over the

Comment: the variables, i am not able to see anything, like wise I added the actualEnvrionment=context.getEvrionment, and it just jumps over from this line to next line and i cant evaluate it. strange this is username, password and initidalldapdirectory properties are always correctly set somehow, i also tried this securty_protcol with ssl. its the same. when it comes to this line with remote debugging, it somehow jumps to bottom of the expression till this control variable, after the context=new InitialDirContext expression. Idk what to do anymore :((

Comment: however if i run the application from eclipse, it works all fine. also i have only one instance of java on my pc and that is amazon coretto 8. i check whihc java is used in eclipse, and its the same aamazon coretto which is also used during running the applicaiton as an external application outside of eclipse

Comment: The debugging problem you indicated usually happens when the compiled code is not up to date with the source code. Is it possible? One thing you can do is include in your code debug traces, nothing fancy, a System.out.println("Environment: " + actualEnvrionment), for example, and see the output, if any, an compare the results obtained when you run the application in eclipse and in prod.

Comment: Hi, I think u re right, so here is what I did. this is a maven project wiht spring boot application. I have this class called BlindSSLFactory, it was in some package, i put this class in another package, and made mvn clean install inside the directory, then i create the jar file. I check the content of the jar file, but i see that this blindssl factory class is still in the old package inside the jar file when i open it with zip. does that mean it there is a compilation error? I think so right? If so, how could I fix this? because mvn clean install compiled all fine :/

Comment: It is very strange indeed. Ahmet, be sure you actually saved the content in the right package and corresponding directory, and do it step by step: first, run `mvn clean`, and verify there is nothing in your target directory. Then, run `mvn clean compile`, and verify if the class is in the right directory. Please, can you try?

Comment: @jccampanero Dear jccampanero, you can't know how much I'm thankful to you. I couldn't find a solution yet but I found  the reason why this was happening. This is a huge project, I'm working at the company. What happens is that, we make a compilation of multiple sub projects and then another submodule called installer is compiled seperately and this installer module calls the jar files from other modules to combine everything together and create an setup.exe. I made mvn clean and mvn compile seperately only in the folder of this specific submodule

Comment: Then, I took this jar, and put it into the installation folder of the application, and i saw that the program then works totally fine. this basically means, somehow during the compilation of this "installer" submodule doesnt find the right jar file correctly, hence its not pickin up the right compiled jar file. This is another problem i have to tackle because i dont know how this happens but at least i found the reason, thank you very much for your long discussion which helped me so much. thanks again..

Comment: That is great Ahmet, I am very happy to know that at least the code related with the ldap server integration is running fine and that the problem is other. Please, if you need further help and you thing I can be of any help, do not hesitate to contact me again, I will be glad to help you if I can.

Comment: Ahmet, the only important thing is that the problem was solved but regarding the question, do you want me to create some kind of answer?

Comment: yeah please do so, i would like to mark it as the answer after your tremendous effort and give it a rating.

Comment: Thank you very much Ahmet, I created an answer. As I told you, if you think that I can be of any help with your new problem or with any other, please, do not hesitate to contact me, I will be glad of help you if I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks fine and all the configuration provided seems to be correct.

After digging into the problem - please, see the different comments on the main question - by applying different configurations and debugging strategies, as you indicated, the problem seems to be related with the way the setup, standalone program, is created, and not with the LDAP server integration code presented in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps your `BlindSSLFactory` is not actually being utilized in the production environment. My money is on `java.naming.ldap.factory.socket` being overridden elsewhere in the code, as it seems to be the means of letting your app know it should utilize this factory via an SPI like interface

A good starting point would be to remote-debug the JVM and see what the property value is set to during runtime.

Comment: Hi @Sheinbergon thank you for your answer. I just did a remote debugging on the prodc application and realized that, when I debug through the lines, the properties are all constructured fine except of this java.naming.ldap.factor.socket line. This property is not added to the properties list at all. Do you have any suggestions as to fix this or what could be the reason ? :/

Comment: @AhmetEroğlu, please, what do you mean when you say _This property is not added to the properties list at all_?

Comment: @jccampanero Hi, in the source code above, can you please see the area where I populate the props variable in the type of Properties. There is my problem, if I run the source code from eclipse, all of those key-value bindings are populated into the props without any problem. However if i run the project as a jar file outside of eclipse, and make remote debugging, i see that only username, userpasword and that context factory is added to properties, when it comes to this socket factory, it doesnt put it in and kind of gives exception.

Comment: @AhmetEroğlu Well,Just to be certain - are you saying you're not seeing them through the debugger, or you're actually printing the environment through the debugger and not seeing those values? I'd suggest  creating a dumb function to print the contents of `props` and evaluate it right before `InitialDirContext` is created. If that's still the case *you're not seeing the variable) well... I suggest you get the jar and decompile it locally. I have a feeling the correct version is not present on the server.

Comment: @Sheinbergon Hi thank you very much for your help, yes u re totally right, I found out about that correct jar file is not correctly fetched to the end product. I dont know how this happens and why but at least i know the problem. Thanks one more time!

Comment: @AhmetEroğlu great. As this is the answer that helped you solve the issue, I'd appreciate if you accept my answer then as the correct one